# Trouble using max(list)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to use max() func to find max value in given a list. 
Im creating a list for a given column from a txt file (representing a table, each line has a name and same amount of data columns).
for example - John,M,53,175,8000 (name,. gender, age, height, salary)
The problem is, I dont know if the column will contain numbers or strings. If the column contains integers, then it looks like this (for example):
['1','40','5','520','1025']
In that case, the max() func is comparing first digit and gives back a wrong value ('520').
Here is the relavant code - (Everything is within a class)
First func. is returning a list of a give column.
The second returns the name/names that has max value of the given column.

```
def get_column(self,colname):
    if colname not in self.columns:
        raise ValueError('Colname doesnt exists')
    col_indx = self.columns.index(colname)+1
    col_data = []   
    for i in range(len(self.names)):            
        col_data.append(self.data[i][col_indx])     
    return col_data 

def get_row_name_with_max_value(self,colname):
    if colname not in self.columns:
        raise ValueError('Colname doesnt exists')
    col_list = self.get_column(colname)
    max_val = max(col_list)
    counter = col_list.count(max_val)
    max_name = []
    k = -1
    for i in range(counter):
        index = col_list.index(max_val, k+1)
        max_name.append(self.data[index][0])
        k = index
    return ', '.join(max_name)
```

thanks alot!

Comment: If there are only strings what should be the maximum value returned?

Comment: the higher value..lets say the list looks like this ['a','b','c'] - so return value should be: c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your list consist only of numeric strings before calling `max`, if this is a case, use `key=int`:

```
def kmax(col):
    key = int if all(x.isdigit() for x in col) else str
    return max(col, key=key)

print kmax(['1','40','5','520','1025']) # 1025
print kmax(['foo','bar','40','baz']) # foo
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the key argument of the `max()` function to specify comparison as ints:

```
In [1]: l = [1,'2',3,'100']

In [2]: max(l, key = int)
Out[2]: '100'
```

Probably you want to apply `int()` to the output as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but what if i have a list in strings?

Comment: It will work for integers now, but if i have a list of strings, its will raise an error. How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand... There are strings in my example. Which error are you getting doing what? Can you make a minimal example?

Comment: I have a database containing : name, age , gender ....  so age is an integer and gender is a string. i have to find a max value from a given column (age, gender etc.). so for example for age i  have a list that looks like this: ['22','32','15','55'] .  and for gender i have a list that looks like this: ['M','F','M','M']. so its pretty stupid to find a max value for gender but it should work anyway.. and for max age - it will work fine if ill use key=int, but incase the list will be gender - it will give an error! thanks in advance!

Comment: Then @thg435 's answer is what you need. I suggest you research pandas data frames if you want to work heavily with mixed data. Then you just do df[column].max() for any data type.